# Fedora and remote mysql in httpd

Tags: fedora, iptables, mysql

Hello I have problem with my fedora (version 24)  httpd server (localhost). I'm install and configure php mysql httpd (and allow rewrite), but when previously I'm using ubuntu I connect to my remote mysql server (from php). Now it not work, and I get error "can't connect to mysql server'.

From php I'm connect like this (wordpress):

```
define('DB_NAME', 'qqqqqqqq');
define('DB_USER', 'qqqqqqq');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'aaaaaaaa');
define('DB_HOST', '111.111.111.111');
```

I try add port 3306 to iptables and still not work. I must work with my remote database in many project not only wp.

Comment: is mysql running? is it blocked via any firewalls? are those the right credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql has it's own acl's, you'll need to grant the user access from a given ip within mysql.

create user...
grant all on `dbname` to `user`@`192.168.0.10` identified by...

Comment: I resolve this, on fedora mysql package haven't mysqli, but some my project use this "mysql version" to connect :)

Comment: However, this does not work...